# Linked list not printing all values

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a linked list as part of a larger project, and have run into an issue. This testcase takes a string of comma delimited ranges (where a range in this case is either an integer or two integers separated by a dash), and add each range into a singly linked list. Currently, it's only printing the first two ranges, and I can't see why. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char port_list[] = "22-25,80,443-445,4200-4205";

    struct range_list {
        struct range_list *next;
        char *range;
    };

    struct range_list *head = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list));
    head->next = 0;
    head->range = strtok(port_list, ",");

    struct range_list *iter = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list));
    head->next = iter;
    iter->next = 0;

    while((iter->range = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL) {
        iter = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list));
        iter->next = iter;
        iter->next = 0;
    }

    for(iter=head; iter != 0; iter=iter->next) {
        printf("%s\n", iter->range);
    }
}
```

Currently, the output is:

```
22-25
80
```

And ideally I would like:

```
22-25
80
443-445
4200-4205
```

Thanks for any help in advance! I'm sure it's a simple issue. I just get scared writing linked lists, so am very out of practice.

Comment: Missing `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Oh oops. ideone didn't complain for some reason.

Comment: `iter = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list)); iter->next = iter;` modifies `iter` *before* assigning to the old `iter`'s `next`.

Comment: ok so should I assign iter to iter->next before mallocing?

Comment: No. You should assign the return value of `malloc()` to a temporary, check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL`, set `iter->next = temporary;`, then `iter = iter->next`.

Comment: After doing that (http://ideone.com/heJvGM) I get a runtime error

Comment: @totoro I'm not sure why... that's how its used.

Comment: You'll also need to check for `NULL` in the printing loop, since you assing `NULL` (from `strtok()`s last return value) to the last `iter`s `range`.

Comment: @DTSCode It wasn't awkward :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has an issue if there's only one range in the string.

I'll therefore propose you a cleaner alternative:

```
...
// as before, assuming ther's at least one range
struct range_list *head = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list));
head->next = 0;
head->range = strtok(port_list, ",");

struct range_list *iter=head, *tmp; 
char *s; 

while((s = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL) {
    // there is a new item.  So first create and initialise it 
    tmp = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list)); 
    tmp->next=0; 
    tmp->range=s; 
    // then link it to the previous and interate
    iter->next = tmp;
    iter = iter->next;
}
...
```

This one assumes that there is at least one range in the string to be put into `head`.

**[Online demo](http://ideone.com/Or8010)**

Note that the `range` pointers point to the original buffer. Here it's not a problem,  because the original buffer remains unchanged.  You may consider `strdup()` if you're on a posix system to make a safe copy of your range string if there's a risk that your linked list lives longer than the buffer or its content.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are overwriting iter:

```
 while((iter->range = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL) {
        iter = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list)); // you are overwriting iter;
        iter->next = iter;
        iter->next = 0;
    }
```

Try this:

```
struct range_list* tmp;
struct range_list* last;



while((iter->range = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL) {
    last = iter;
    tmp = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list)); 
    iter->next = tmp;
    iter = iter->next;
    iter->next = 0;
}
free(last->next);
last->next = 0;


for(iter=head; iter != 0; iter=iter->next) {
    printf("%s\n", iter->range);
}
```

Comment: @DTSCode where you get? Maybe in the print loop. because you are printing null value.

Comment: @DTSCode just tried. It works! Your problem is into the print loop

Comment: @DTSCode I edited avoiding runtime error into pint loop

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. I think it's basically the same everyone is saying in different words.

[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/BhdO8N)

```
char port_list[] = "22-25,80,443-445,4200-4205";
char *range;
// Create the head and start the tokener.
struct range_list *iter, *head = calloc(1, sizeof(struct range_list));
head->range = strtok(port_list, ",");

// As long as there is a token append a new item.    
while((range = strtok(NULL, ",")) != NULL) {
    iter = (struct range_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct range_list));
    iter->next = head;
    iter->range = range;
    head = iter;
}

for(iter=head; iter != 0; iter=iter->next) {
    printf("%s\n", iter->range);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4200-4205
443-445
80
22-25
```